# How does WebView work in a mobile device? (starts a new browser?)

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm new to android. I have a question related to WebView.
It's not clear to me how WebView works.

When we use a WebView, does the mobile start a new browser in order to load 
the URL (even if the url is online or locally stored on the mobile)?

Cause, I would like to create a native android app (test.apk) with WebView
and its's not clear to me if the app starts from the browser or from
an inline View.

Any tutorial or example would be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: The WebView is a web browser itself. Imagine it as an embedded window over the web. It can also run JavaScript. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Comment: Is WebView a browser?

Comment: What do you define as a browser?

Comment: Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE etc

Comment: Yes, it is (meaning that it lets you browse the internet like a browser). In the form of a component you can add to your design.

Comment: So, can I create a test.apk application based only on WebViews(with no internet connection)? is that a good solution? How is that app going to be called (web app or native app?)

Comment: Hmmm... You COULD. If it is a good solution is opinion based. In my opinion, NO. HTML is even worst performant than Java itself. Note that Android lets you develop in native C++, if you want to (by using the NDK instead of the SDK). Which is MUUUUUUCH faster.

Comment: I would like to load an offline open street map(.mbtiles format), create markers, POIs,navigation etc and I've seen some javascript libraries like leaflet.js that contain APIs for interactive maps. As I understood someone can create html pages and use the leaflet javascript library in order to create the maps.

Comment: Tutorial on using Maps: [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Comment: The problem about apps-inside-a-webview is that it never "feels" 100% native to the user. You just notice that controls look and act slightly differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WebView is a view that displays web content right inside your app. It does not have fancy stuff like bookmarks or a history view, but you could build a full featured browser around a `WebView`. Imagine a `WebView` as a view that displays a web page.

If you want to start an external web browser app, you can use an Intent to let the system find a suitable app to handle your url.

Comment: So, can I create html pages in android and then load them in WebViews? Also, what's the difference between WebView and other Views of android?

Comment: WebView is for HTML files / urls (or even strings containing HTML tags). Other Views are specialized into other things: ImageView for Images, TextViews for strings, EditTexts for string input, Buttons for... well, clicking - and so on.

Comment: Yes, you can load html pages into `WebView`s.

Answer (score 1):

Webview is :

- View that displays web pages.
- Provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript
- Uses WebKit rendering engine to display web pages and includes methods to navigate forward and backward through a history, zoom in and out.

Check [Android Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for detailed information.

Comment: If i Write an html page and I include Javascript in it? Can this be enabled?